# How to declare in requirejs that a module has already been loaded sync

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have a requirejs module that depends on jquery. Instead of loading jquery from a directory, I decided to add it statically in the webpage as a `<script>` entry from a CDN. requirejs however keeps attempting to load from file.

Is there a way of telling requirejs that a given dependency is added in the HTML and therefore it should not retrieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no configuration option to tell RequireJS that something is already loaded. However, you can create a fake `jquery` module that will just give access to the jQuery that you've already loaded through a script:

```
define("jquery", function () {
  return jQuery;
});
```

When I do something like this, I add this fake module just before my call to `require.config`. I find that it is a convenient place for it.

Also, make sure that the `script` element that loads jQuery appears before the `script` that loads RequireJS. Otherwise, jQuery will detect RequireJS and call `define` itself, and you'll get an error.